# Access entries in a ResourceDictionary from binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to create a similar accentcolor-picking system like Windows Phones has, where all the available colors are displayed in a grid of squares.

Mahapps.Metro has this object called Accent which has a name (string), and a resource dictionary attached to it. So in my Listbox I'm trying to bind to those items.

Here's how my XAML looks like

```
<ListBox x:Name="accentChooserBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="accentChooserBox_PreviewMouseDoubleClick" SelectionMode="Single">
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Background="{Binding Path=???}" Height="50" Width="50">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Light" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
```

I want to set the Grid's background to be the AccentColor of the Accent.
Here is also an example of how the Resourcedictionary looks like

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Color x:Key="HighlightColor">#FF5133AB</Color>

<Color x:Key="AccentColor">#CC6459DF</Color> <--- I want to bind to this
<!--60%-->
<Color x:Key="AccentColor2">#996459DF</Color>
<!--40%-->
<Color x:Key="AccentColor3">#666459DF</Color>
<!--20%-->
<Color x:Key="AccentColor4">#336459DF</Color>

<!-- re-set brushes too -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush" Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush2" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor2}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush3" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor3}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush4" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor4}"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowTitleColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentSelectedColorBrush" Color="White" />

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBrush" EndPoint="0.001,0.5" StartPoint="1.002,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource AccentColor3}" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckmarkFill" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RightArrowFill" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />

<Color x:Key="IdealForegroundColor">White</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="IdealForegroundColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource IdealForegroundColor}"/>
```

How would I go about writing this in the Grid's Background property? I tried using `Background="{Binding Path=Resources.AccentColor}"` but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you merge the resource dictionary into your resources, you can access it directly:

```
<ListBox ...>
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Path/To/YourResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ListBox.Resources>
```

Then, just use it:

```
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>      
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Background="{Binding Path=AccentColor}" Height="50" Width="50">
```

Comment: But there are about 20 of those dictionaries, one each for every accentcolor.

Comment: @Tokfrans Make one resource dictionary that merges tehm all in, then merge that one in where you need it as necessary